# Ambiguities Make Arguments

Tags: word, knowledge, story

Linda and Matthew were given a word, 11 letters.

> **Linda:** Well, we can use this word for water.
>
> **Matthew:** Huh? It sounds like you don't know water is made of atoms.
>
> **Linda:** What? What about using this word for love?
>
> **Matthew:** That's even more absurd. Love cannot even be measured.
>
> **Linda:** How is that *more* absurd when you're actually concurring by that last sentence?
>
> **Matthew:** Listen, this word is used for things that are too *many*!
>
> **Linda:** You cannot say "many" for the things that this word is used for!

What is the word given, and why isn't Matthew convinced?

Comment: @WOWOW Please consider what Matthew was thinking. Blind guessing isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> **Uncountable.**

> Linda: Well, we can use this word for water.
>
> Matthew: Huh? It sounds like you don't know water is made of atoms.

> Linda looks at water and sees it to be a fluid; you can count grains of sand, or rocks, or people, but you don't typically "count" water, you measure it, typically in litres.
>
>
> Matthew rebuts her by saying that water is made of atoms, making the point that they could be counted.

> Linda: What? What about using this word for love?
>
> Matthew: That's even more absurd. Love cannot even be measured.
>
> Linda: How is that more absurd when you're actually concurring by that last sentence?

> Linda suggests using "uncountable" for love. It sounds strange and ill-fitting, and Matthew highlights this fact. But, Linda ripostes by explaining that his rebuttal actually proves her point.
>
>
>  Love literally cannot be measured, and so it is literally uncountable.

> Matthew: Listen, this word is used for things that are too many!
>
> Linda: You cannot say "many" for the things that this word is used for!

> Finally, Matthew makes the point that the word ("uncountable") is in reference to an infinite number of things. That is, a quantity of things that is infinite, and so cannot be counted.
>
>
>  Linda, staying on form, holds to the literal view; if something is "uncountable", you can't count it. You can't say "many" because you can't count it to begin with.

Regarding the names as clues:

> **Matth**ew always takes a **math**ematical approach; his views reflect the academic meaning of the term; an infinite set.
>
>
>  **Li**nda always takes a **lin**guistic view. She approaches the problem in terms of the English language and phrasing, which is why she often appears to be speaking in very literal terms.

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: On it, editing now.

Comment: All done :) Hope that's right!

Comment: Spoiler parts in answers must be hidden in spoiler blocks. And I think you're overthinking this. Please try to explain the clues accurately, for you got the word right.

Comment: Hint: rot13(Gur anzrf "Yvaqn" naq "Znggurj" ner nyfb pyhrf.)

Comment: Redone. I'm reasonably happy for the first two clues, the latter I've rejiggered as I agree that it was a little stiff. Thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147574/discussion-between-dannyu-ndos-and-conniemnemonic).

Comment: I'm in there :)